# Lodash , check if object exists and property exists and is true

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, lodash

Good morning . I need help on checking if object exists and certain propertie have value of true. Ex:

```
validations={
  "DSP_INDICADOR": {
    "required": true
  },
  "EMPRESA": {
    "required": true
  },
.....
  "NOME_AVAL": {
    "required": false,
    "notEqualToField": "NOME"
  }
}
```

and then check for `required:true`

Thanks in advance

Comment: _.filter(validations, function(o) { return o.required; }) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this would be it.

```
if (validations["EMPRESA"] && validations["EMPRESA"].required) {
  console.log(true)
} else {
  console.log(false)
}
```

Answer (score 9):

How about simply using

`_.get(validations, "EMPRESA.required");` in lodash

In this way we can fetch upto any depth, and we don't need to assure with consecutive `&&` again and again that the immediate parent level exists first for each child level.

You can use this `_.get` in a more programmatic way with a default value (if the path not exist) and a `array` of `keys` in proper sequence for lookup. So, dynamically you can pass array of keys to fetch values and you don't need to create a string for that joined by `.` like `"EMPRESA.required"` (in the case your input for `N` depth lookup path is not a `string`)

Here is an example:

```js
let obj = {a1: {a2: {a3: {a4: {a5: {value: 101}}}}}};

let path1 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4', 'a5', 'value'], //valid
    path2 = ['a1', 'a2', 'a3', 'a4'], //valid
    path3 = ['a1', 'a3', 'a2', 'x', 'y', 'z']; //invalid
    
console.log(`Lookup for ${path1.join('->')}: `, _.get(obj, path1));
console.log(`Lookup for ${path2.join('->')}: `, _.get(obj, path2));
console.log(`Lookup for ${path3.join('->')}: `, _.get(obj, path3));
console.log(`Lookup for ${path3.join('->')} with default Value: `, _.get(obj, path3, 404));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.10/lodash.min.js"></script>
```