# Checking 'undefined' or 'null' of any Object

Tags: javascript, angular, lodash

I am working on Angular project and time to time I used to have check `undefined` or `null` over Object or it's properties. Normally I use lodash `_.isUndefined()` see example below:

```
this.selectedItem.filter(i => {
    if(_.isUndefined(i.id)) {
      this.selectedItem.pop();
    }
})
```

I couldn't see any problem with it. But I had discussion with my colleague during review of above code. He was telling me that if `i` gets `undefined` before the `if` statement then it will throw the exception. Instead he suggested me to always check `i` or `i.id` like this:

```
if(!!i && !!i.id) {
      this.selectedItem.pop();
}
```

I am convinced what he was trying to say unlike his way of checking `undefined` in above code. But then I was thinking what is the purpose of lodash `_.isUndefined`?

Could anyone please let me know what is the best or clean way to do it. Because for me `!!i && !!i.id` is not readable at all.

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you look at the function `typeof()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof ?

Comment: in your angular project, are you using typescript or just javascript?

Comment: `if(!!i && !!i.id)` does a ***different*** check than `_.isUndefined`!!! It will check if the property is truthy, not if it's `undefined`. It will also catch `null`, `0`, and `""` (empty string), for example.  Also, the first implicit boolean conversion `!!i` is superfluous.

Comment: @Anouar Yes I am using TS

Comment: I'am usually use if (!variable). Well if variable is a string and is equal to "" or is a number and is equal to 0, the condition is true

Comment: For reference, here [is the table for truthyness](https://dorey.github.io/JavaScript-Equality-Table/) - on the top of the page, you can go to the tab for `if()` which shows how different values behave as a condition.

Comment: Thanks @vlaz I'll take a look on this.

Answer (score 36, accepted):

You can use [`_.isNil()`](https://lodash.com/docs/#isNil) to detect `undefined` or `null`. Since you're using [`Array.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter), you want to return the results of `!_.isNil()`. Since `i` is supposed to be an object, you can use `!_.isNil(i && i.id)`.

Note: you are using `Array.filter()` as [`Array.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach). The callback of `Array.filter()` should return a boolean, and the result of the filter is a new array.

```js
const selectedItem = [
  undefined,
  {},
  { id: 5 },
  undefined,
  { id: 7 },
];

const result = selectedItem.filter(i => !_.isNil(i?.id));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

You can also use [`_.reject()`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#reject) and save the need to add `!`:

```js
const selectedItem = [
  undefined,
  {},
  { id: 5 },
  undefined,
  { id: 7 },
];

const result = _.reject(selectedItem, i => _.isNil(i?.id));

console.log(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 4):

Use `typeof i.id === 'undefined'` to check for `undefined` and `i.id === null` to check for `null`.

You could write your own helper functions to wrap any logic like what LoDash has. The condition with `!!i && !!i.id` is only looking for falsy values (empty string, `0`, etc), not only `null` or `undefined`.

Comment: I have suggested that in the comments but there is this one stupid thing with `NaN` eg. `typeof(NaN)`  -> returns `"number"`

Comment: @tutorialfeed thats up to your standards.

Answer (score 3):

You could check for `i` and if it is not truthy or if the property is `undefined` or `null`, then do something.

```
if (!i || i.id === undefined || i.id === null) {
    this.selectedItem.pop();
}
```

Comment: Yep. This is the correct answer. (I was just about to write the exact same thing)

Answer (score 3):

Referring to a variable which has `undefined` as it's value won't throw any error. You get a `ReferenceError` for referring to variable that is *not defined*:

```
> i
Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined
```

If you pass a not-defined variable to a function a `ReferenceError` is thrown and the function won't be executed.

```
> _.isUndefined(i)
Uncaught ReferenceError: i is not defined
```

`typeof` operator should be used for safely checking whether a variable is defined or not:

```
> typeof i
'undefined'
```

In your code the `i` *is defined* (it's a function argument) so by referring to it you won't get any `ReferenceError`. The code will throw a `TypeError` when `i` is defined, *has `undefined` value* and you are treating it as an object:

```
> var i = undefined; i.id
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined
```

Comment: Answer straight from the source :P

Comment: Yes I did this check in the console but my intention was to write more clean and readable code. :)

Answer (score 2):

Your friend is right. When you do, `_.isUndefined(i.id)` you're assuming `i` to not to be `undefined`. You're assuming `i` is an object which will have an `id` property which you're checking if it is **falsey** or not.

What happens when the variable `i` itself is `undefined`? So you will end up `undefined.id` which is an error. Therefore you could simply do this

```
if(i && i.id) {
  // You're good to go
}
```

The above will check for all *falsey* values, `0` and `""` included. So if you want to be very specific, then you'll have to check the types of both using `typeof` operator.

Comment: Unless `i.id` is zero. Or if it's an empty string. Both probably should not happen, but it might with some mock data or some synthetic records.

Answer (score 2):

```js
let words = [null, undefined, 'cheaters', 'pan', 'ear', 'era']

console.log(words.filter(word => word != null));
```

Answer (score 1):

May I suggest checking for `if(typeof(element) == "number" && element) {}` In this case the `typeof()` part catches any non numbers and the `element` part should catch any `NaN`s (`typeof(NaN)` returns "number")

Answer (score 1):

You can use [lodash#get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get) (it will handle if the root is value null or undefined), and then compare the output with null using `==` or `!=`, instead of using `===` or `!==`. if the output is `null` or `undefined` then comparing with `==` will be true and `!=` will be false.

```js
const selectedItem = [
  undefined,
  {},
  {id: null},
  { id: 5 },
  undefined,
  { id: 0 },
  { id: 7 },
];

const res = selectedItem.filter(a => _.get(a, 'id') != null);

console.log(res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

using [lodash#get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get) you can checkfor any nested level for its existence with out subsequent `&&` like `a && a.b && a.b.c && a.b.c.d` (in case of `d`) look at [this answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47885165/lodash-check-if-object-exists-and-property-exists-and-is-true/47887596#47887596) for nested level checking with [lodash#get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#get)

Also you can use `_.isNill` instead of comparing with `null` will `==` or `!=`

Answer (score 1):

Another more "lodashy" approach would be to use [**_.conforms**](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#conforms). The readability is much better in my opinion and you get access directly to `id` so no problems with undefined before that:

```js
const items = [
  undefined,
  { id: null},
  { id: 5 },
  { id: "4" },
  { id: undefined },
  undefined,
  { id: 0 },
  { id: 7 },
  { id: () => 3 }
];

const numbersOnly = _.filter(items, _.conforms({'id': _.isNumber}));
console.log('numbers', numbersOnly);

const allDefined = _.filter(items, _.conforms({'id': _.negate(_.isUndefined)}));
console.log('defined', allDefined);

const stringsOnly = _.filter(items, _.conforms({'id': _.isString}));
console.log('strings', stringsOnly);

const functionsOnly = _.filter(items, _.conforms({'id': _.isFunction}));
console.log('functions', functionsOnly);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.11/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Javascript has now (Chrome 80, Safari 13.4) [Optional chaining (?.)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Optional_chaining)

> The optional chaining operator (?.) permits reading the value of a
> property located deep within a chain of connected objects without
> having to expressly validate that each reference in the chain is
> valid.

This means you could check for id without causing an exception in case i is undefined

```
this.selectedItem.filter(i => {
  if(i?.id) {
    this.selectedItem.pop();
  }
})
```

Or since you are using filter, you can check [test this live on the filter documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).

```
const words = ['spray', undefined, 'elite', 'exuberant', 'destruction', 'present'];

const result = words.filter(word => word?.length > 6);

console.log(result);
// expected output: Array ["exuberant", "destruction", "present"]
```

Additionally, also worth to mention, as @Koushik Chatterjee's answer points, [lodash _.get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get) allows you to describe a path to a deep property safely, and even give a default value in case it doesn't exist.

```
var object = { 'a': [{ 'b': { 'c': 3 } }] };
_.get(object, ['a', '0', 'b', 'c']);
// => 3

_.get(object, 'a.b.c', 'default');
// => 'default'
```